# filter contours for lines

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a black and white image of line drawings that may look something like the following: [image: o]

but can be much more complicated.

I want to convert this drawing into a `std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>` (pretty much a contour). Except the problem is i cant simply call contour. Calling contour will give me an ordered set of points which outline this shape. I want ordered set of points (maybe even multiple of them) that will give me back the line itself.

This is very close to the contour problem, except "half" the amount of points are needed.

I have written a method which will find me points that are "connectors", and points that are "endPoints".

So in the example, there are 3 endPoints, and 1 connector.

My algorithm is as follows:

```
get actual contours = [[contour]]
classify points to get [endPoints], [connections] map

criticalSeen = 0
for each contour in contours
     If seen[current point] continue;

     If criticalSeen >= 1
          append current point to currPoints
          seen[current point] = true
     If criticalSeen == 0
         continue

     If criticalSeen == 2
          criticalSeen = 1
          append currPoints to result
          reset currPoints to empty
return result
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a), `contours` contains "Detected contours. Each contour is stored as a vector of points (e.g. std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >)." So you would just iterate over each vector. You might also want to look at [`approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contourarea#approxpolydp).

Comment: Hi beaker would you mind if I ask you to give inputs on a current algorithm I am working on?

Comment: If you post it in a question (either this one or a new one) I'll have a look, and we can get input from others as well.

Comment: I added full problem

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. What is this algorithm attempting to do? What sort of feedback are you expecting?

Comment: It seems that the algorithm struggles with certain cases. i am just wondering if there is a more systematic way of solving this. The algorithm is supposed to give me ordered vectors of points which describe the input.

Comment: I can describe more over mail if you are willing.

Comment: I have an idea that I think will work, but there are some implementations details to iron out, and an edge case or two which id be down to discuss